# How to sort a data frame with a sorting algorithm (eg. bubble sort)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, bubble-sort

I can't sort a pandas data frame with the bubble sorting algorithm i've built. Can someone help me understand the problem?

The list is a list where each element is a dictionary with a key and a value.

here is my code

[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqo0A.png)
[image: my code]

Comment: def bubble_sort(lst, x = "name"):
    swap = False
    while swap != True:
        swap = True
        for i in range(1, len(lst)):
            if lst[i-1] > lst[i]:
                swap = False
                lst[i-1], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[i-1]
    return pd.DataFrame(lst)

bubble_sort(persons, x = "ssn")

Comment: I don't recommend creating your own sorting algorithms for pandas data frames.  There is a prebuilt function called .sort_values that allows you to specify which columns and what hierarchy to sort.  The method is optimized in C, so it's highly unlikely you sort faster than the method written in Python.    Pandas already has the sorting overhead, so use it and don't reinvent the wheel! 
 https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: @finman69 thank you! Yes i know there's an easier way than this but this is a school assignment haha so unfortunately I've no choice:((

Comment: Oh no, that's cruelty.  If you can show how you call your method in the question I could help some more.  Also, are you just trying to sort a column/row without regard to order of the rest of the dataframe?